# Error making a []map[string]interface{} with for loop -> panic: assignment to entry in nil map

Tags: arrays, dictionary, for-loop, go, slice

Im trying to build a []map[string]interface{} using a loop like so:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type People []struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

func main() {
    resp := `[{"name":"Test","age":15}, {"name":"Test2","age":25}]`
    data := &People{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp), data)
    m := make([]map[string]interface{}, len(*data))
    for k, v := range *data {
        m[k]["Name"] = v.Name
        m[k]["Age"] = v.Age
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Printf("%T", m)
}
```

But Im always getting this error:

> panic: assignment to entry in nil map
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.main()    /tmp/sandbox300360207/prog.go:19
>   +0x17a

I cant use `m := make(People, len(*data))` and `m[k].Name = v.Name` because I need the type to be `[]map[string]interface{}` and not main.People

I also tried this:

```
func main() {
    resp := `[{"name":"Test","age":15}, {"name":"Test2","age":25}]`
    data := &People{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp), data)
    m := make([]map[string]interface{}, len(*data))
    for k, v := range *data {
        m[k] = map[string]interface{"Name": v.Name, "Age": v.Age}
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Printf("%T", m)
}
```

But got this error:

> ./prog.go:19:31: syntax error: unexpected literal "Name", expecting
>   method or interface name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `make()` only creates a slice of maps, but its elements are all `nil`s. You can't "insert" pairs into a `nil` map, you also have to create maps inside the loop:

```
m := make([]map[string]interface{}, len(*data))
for k, v := range *data {
    m[k] = make(map[string]interface{})
    m[k]["Name"] = v.Name
    m[k]["Age"] = v.Age
}
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CnaTQFuvsys)):

```
[map[Age:15 Name:Test] map[Age:25 Name:Test2]]
[]map[string]interface {}
```

Alternatively you may use a composite literal to create the map:

```
m[k] = map[string]interface{}{}
```

Your second attempt falls short because the syntax is invalid. The type is `map[string]interface{}`, so a composite literal to create a value of this type has to have an additional braces pair: `map[string]interface{}{}`. Using a single composite literal, this is how it would look like:

```
for k, v := range *data {
    m[k] = map[string]interface{}{
        "Name": v.Name,
        "Age":  v.Age,
    }
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-KiiDu4utwl).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense and its working now, thanks a lot!